# What do we call a person who understands technical things with ease?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice

The title makes this pretty straightfoward. Is there an english word or words for someone who can understand technical things with ease, or at least more easily than the average person?

Comment: My native language is not english. What do you think about `furtive` or `(in)genious`?

Comment: Savant or you would say they have a natural talent

Comment: What do you mean “technical things”? Technology or something more broader than that? If the latter, you would seem to be looking for the word smart    :|

Comment: You can say they are *technically minded*.

Comment: @Nikos "Furtive" doesn't have anything to do with technical adeptness, it means sneaky or secretive.

Comment: As you are apparently learning English, (or at least the orthography) you be interested to know that in English languages and nationalities are always capitalized. Not to do this can be considered slightly insulting, so it is well to remember this. Also, please take the trouble to make the question stand on its own. A title is a title, a question should explain clearly your problem. For example you don’t make it sufficiently clear whether you want a noun or an adjective, and how formal a word you require. “Techie” is the obvious informal noun, but I suspect that is not what you are after.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe tech-savvy. I’m sure there are several other hyphenated options, too. Tech-genius. There’s also technical whiz.

Answer (score 1):

**whiz kid** (Only applies to young people)

> noun Informal. a youthful and exceptionally intelligent, successful,
> or influential person in a given field: the whiz kid of network
> programming.
> https://www.dictionary.com/browse/whiz-kid

**EDITED**

I think what @Richard Kayser said in the comments is good, e.g.

Have you met John, he's a real tech wizard!  (There are plenty of online search results for this phrase)

or, slightly more formally:

Have you met John, he's a real technical wizard!

Comment: I like **whiz kid**, but it's not specific to technical wizardry. One could be a **whiz kid** in tennis, chess, or any number of other areas.

Comment: Whiz, wiz, and wizard, which are broader than whiz kid, would also work if they connoted technical wizardry only, but they don't. It would seem one needs an adjective, e.g., technical whiz, wiz, or wizard.

Answer (score 0):

The British often use “boffin”.